# Cursor and if - else if statement issue

Tags: sql, t-sql

I try to do this,

```
DECLARE cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT col1, col2, col3 ... FROM t1 WHERE...
OPEN cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor INTO @col1, @col2, @col3
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN   
       IF(@col1 = 1)
       BEGIN
          update u
          set u.col1=2
          from t1 u
          where ...
       END
       ELSE IF(@col1 <> 1)
       BEGIN
         update u
          set u.col1=3
          from t1 u
          where ...
       END
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor INTO @col1, @col2, @col3
    END
CLOSE cursor_sala_curso
DEALLOCATE cursor_sala_curso
```

The problem is, when IF(@col1 = 1) update a record, that record enter in ELSE IF condition too and update the record col1 to 3

Suppose the result set of the cursor has 5 records, three records with col1 with a value of 1 and two records with col1 with a value of 2, the above code update t1 10 times, not 5.

Why enter into two statements?

The result set of cursor change if I update a row of the table?

```
col1  col2    initial result set of cursor
  1    10
  1    11
  1    12
  2    13
  2    13 

col1  col2    final result set with above code
  3    10
  3    11
  3    12
  3    13
  3    13 

 col1  col2    expected result set with above code
  2    10
  2    11
  2    12
  3    13
  3    13
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do yoy really need a cursor?

Comment: @jarlh its an example, the real code is more complex with more variables and a simple massive update its not the solution

Comment: Perhaps a "massive update" with `case` expressions, e.g. `update T1 set Col1 = case when @Col1 = 1 then 2 else Col1 end, Col2 = ... where ...`? Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: Because the first run you update all 1 values to 2; second run you update all values <> 1 to 3; so the third run everything is 3, so all values are updated to 3... What is the exact purpose?

Comment: good answers but i need to know why above code realize 10 updates and not 5

Comment: I don't know why it updates 10 times in your case. If I place a print message in the body of the IF clause and one in the body of the ELSE IF clause, I get 5 messages, not 10...

Comment: @Kevin yeah but why ? the result set of cursor change if i update a record ? if the first col1 = 1 change to 2, should not go to the next record? because i update the record not the col1 variable

Comment: Yes, if you place print @col1 just before your IF(@col1 = 1) you get the results 1, 2, 3, 3, 3. So the col1 values are updated.

Comment: It does not update 10 times.  Run it in debug and see for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you don't need `cursor` here. Try this query:

```
update t1
set col1 = case when col1 = 1 then 2 else 3 end
```

Comment: its an example, the real code is more complex with more variables and a simple massive update its not the solution

Comment: @Carlos, then provide either your full query or sample data with more columns covering your issue

Comment: @Carlos . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you specifically ask.  This is the best answer to the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Users are encouraged to create a minimum representation of the problem.  In this case what the OP claims is happening is simply not happening.  If they had run the minimum representation they would see this.

Answer (score 1):

What you claim is happening is not correct
There is something else going on but you are very close minded

```
declare @T table (pk int identity primary key, col1 int);
insert into @T (col1) values (1), (2), (1), (3);
select * from @T;
declare @pk int, @col1 int;
DECLARE cursr CURSOR FOR SELECT pk, col1 FROM @T
OPEN cursr
FETCH NEXT FROM cursr INTO @Pk, @col1
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN   
       IF(@col1 = 1)
       BEGIN
          update @T 
          set col1 = 2
          where pk = @pk
       END
       ELSE IF(@col1 <> 1)
       BEGIN
          update @T 
          set col1 = 5
          where pk = @pk
       END
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursr INTO @Pk, @col1
    END
CLOSE cursr
DEALLOCATE cursr;
select * from @T;

pk          col1
----------- -----------
1           1
2           2
3           1
4           3

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

pk          col1
----------- -----------
1           2
2           5
3           2
4           5
```